# Remove property from yaml file

Tags: go, struct, type-conversion

I need to read yaml file and change some properties value and write it back to the FS.

The file content is like this

```
ID: mytest
mod:
- name: user
  type: dev
  parameters:
    size: 256M
  build:
    builder: mybuild


type OBJ struct {
    Id            string      `yaml:"ID"`
    Mod           []*Mod   `yaml:"mod,omitempty"`
}


type Mod struct {
    Name       string
    Type       string
    Parameters       Parameters `yaml:"parameters,omitempty"`
    Build            Parameters `yaml:"build,omitempty"`

}
```

I need to omit the `type` property from the output

```
ID: mytest
mod:
- name: user
  parameters:
    size: 256M
  build:
    builder: mybuild
```

The problem is that, I can read it, I can change the property value but can not delete the key (which is `type`)

The code I use

```
yamlFile, err := ioutil.ReadFile("test.yaml")

//Here I parse the file to the model I’ve which is working fine
err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(yamlFile), &obj)
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("Yaml file is not valid, Error: " + err.Error())
    os.Exit(-1)
}
```

Now I was able to loop on the properties like

```
obj := models.OBJ{}


for i, element := range obj.Mod {

//Here I was able to change property data

mta.Mod[i].Name = "test123"
```

But not sure how I can omit the whole property of `type` when writing back to the FS.

I use this OS: 
https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml/tree/v2

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: @aerokite - with your suggestion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to omit `type` from your whole YAML, you can Marshal your data into an object where `type` is not more exists

```
type OBJ struct {
    Id  string `yaml:"ID"`
    Mod []*Mod `yaml:"mod,omitempty"`
}

type Mod struct {
    Name        string
    //Type      string `yaml:"type"`
    Parameters  Parameters `yaml:"parameters,omitempty"`
    Build       Parameters `yaml:"build,omitempty"`
}
```

`type` will be removed, if you Marshal your data into this object.

**Another solution** if you do not want to use multiple object.

Use `omitempty` in Type. So when value of Type is `""`, it will be ignored

```
type Mod struct {
    Name       string
    Type       string `yaml:"type,omitempty"`
    Parameters  Parameters `yaml:"parameters,omitempty"`
    Build       Parameters `yaml:"build,omitempty"`
}
```

And do this

```
for i, _ := range obj.Mod {
    obj.Mod[i].Type = ""
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to add this:

```
type Mod struct {
    Name       string     `yaml:"name"`
    Type       string     `yaml:"type,omitempty"` // note the omitempty
    Parameters Parameters `yaml:"parameters,omitempty"`
    Build      Parameters `yaml:"build,omitempty"`
}
```

Now if you do this (inside loop if you like):

```
obj.Mod[0].Type = "" // set to nil value of string
byt, _ := yaml.Marshal(obj)
```

And write the `byt` to file, the type will be removed.

The point is any struct field that has a `omitempty` tag, when marshalling with `yaml.Marshal` it will **omit** (remove) the field if it is **empty** (aka has `nil` value).

More info in [official documentation](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/yaml.v2#Marshal).